# Spy on component method before TestBed.createComponent()

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular7

I am using AG-Grid which provides a call-back method for when the table has finished initializing.

I need to make sure this method is called when the table has finished initializing but I'm not sure what way to go about it. The method needs to be spied on before the component is actually created because it will have already been called without being triggered explicitly in my test.

I have tried setting up a spy and then re-creating the component using `TestBed.createComponent()` but I don't think the spy works because it's hooked into the previously created `fixture.componentInstance`.

The Grid:

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
  id="strategyListGrid"
  [rowData]="strategyList$ | async"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Component Function:

```
/**
 * Fetch GridApi from initialized ag-grid
 * @param params GridEvent fired from component when initialization has completed
 */
onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.triggerTableResize();
}
```

Test Code:

```
function setup() {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StrategyListComponent);
    let app = fixture.componentInstance;
    return { app, fixture };
}

it('should resize the table when grid is ready', () => {
    const { fixture, app } = setup();
    let resizeSpy = spyOn(app, 'onGridReady');
    let fixtureRefresh = TestBed.createComponent(StrategyListComponent);
    fixtureRefresh.detectChanges();
    fixtureRefresh.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(resizeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

This fails with:
`Expected spy onGridReady to have been called`

I'm not convinced this is the correct way to spy on the component method before it's created. But if it is, it's possible I need to use `fakeAsync` to wait so time before the method is called.

**EDIT: I have a working version but it's not very clean**

```
it(
        'should resize the table when grid is ready',
        fakeAsync(() => {
            const { app, fixture } = setup();
            let gridReadySpy = spyOn(app, 'onGridReady');
            fixture.detectChanges();
            flush();

            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                fixture.detectChanges(); // Refresh template view
                flush();
                expect(gridReadySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        })
    );
```

Comment: You shouldn't spy on the component under test anyway; what's the *behaviour* implemented here?

Comment: The component has a Service injected into the constructor, it assigns 'service.getList()' observable to 'strategyList$' - this get's resolved using the async pipe on the table. When the table has rendered, it calls 'onGridReady' on the component.
I want to make sure when the component is created, it eventually calls onGridReady.

Comment: I have got the test working but I don't think it's a very clean test.
Why shouldn't you spy on the component under test btw?

Comment: Because it's the thing you're supposedly testing. Test it through its public API; `@Input`s, the rendered DOM, and interactions with collaborators.

Comment: Agreeing with jonrsharpe. Instead of trying to verify, that ag-grid does it‘s job of emitting (gridReady) at the right moment, you would want to test your component and what it does when this eventEmitter is triggered, wouldn‘t you? So instead of spying onto the method inside of your component, I would rather assert, that the params are set inside the component and the table is resized. To achieve that I wouldn‘t even use the real ag-grid component but just use the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA

Comment: I see. Thank you both - I think my lines are getting blurred between testing my component and testing the child component does its job like you said. I think I will focus more on unit testing for my angular component. Thanks, guys.